# Are these right angle projections correct?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Are these right angle projections correct?

https://postimg.org/image/64l4ibu25/

https://postimg.org/image/pnpprostp/

Comment: What makes you think they aren't?

Comment: @Wasabi I just want to make sure they are.

Comment: please check my homework, really?

Comment: Ah, but why accept my answer?  If the OP understands the question sufficiently, then the answers become obvious in this case!  I always thought homework was part of the learning process. If there is an answer without some level of understanding, then that defeats the purpose of education.  So, OP was my answer correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Link 6414ibu25 is missing a dashed (hidden) line in the upper left projection on the first image.
The second image in 6414ibu25 appears to be correct

Link pnpprostp - the upper right image is projected from the wrong side. 
The lower image in pnpprostp is correct.

Comment: Thanks. But just to clarify about the first correction are you saying that the problem is at the first picture the image on the frontal image is wrong and at the second page the lateral projection is wrong?

Comment: Yes that is correct